# Accurate Computation

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

When looking for $x$-values for which $f(x) =1 - \sin(x)$ cannot be accurately computed, we have to look for values the operands are  very close in value; in this case this happens when $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Why is it then, when evaluating the function for a larger number such as $10^{27}$ the calculator gives an error? Does this means that we cannot accurately computed for large $x$-values, too?

Comment: This may sound strange, but you have to be very specific with what you mean by 'accurately' — do you want a _fixed_ error, or relative accuracy in terms of the value of the result? The latter is what seems to be suggested by your initial example. In any case, 'the calculator gives an error' should not be in any way shape or form taken as 'the value is hard to compute accurately'; the former is a statement about _the calculator_ while the latter is a statement about the mathematics.

Comment: Most probably the calculator is not reducing $10^{27} \bmod 2\pi$ accurately.

Comment: Thank you both for clarifying this to me.